# How do we write unit tests for MIP (Microsoft Information Protection) using C# programming language?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, file, tdd, mip-sdk

**Requirement**: If any file has protection(Sensitivity label) then we are throwing an error message.

Before we go and do our actual implementation, I want to achieve this using TDD approach.

**Please let me clarify whether the below steps can we achieve using unit test with C#?**

1. Is it possible to write unit test on this MIP? If yes,

   - Through program , I want to read the file(.pdf or office app files) and apply sensitivity label before  using MIP Code.
   - Once it reaches MIP code snippet ,this should detect this file and it has protection.
   - If it is protected then should throw an error message or else skip the execution.

Answer (score 0):

I never used the MIP SDK, but you are in the wrong path if you want to test the file information using MIP.

**1. Use double testing**

First you will have to use Double Testing **(a stub or a fake)** to be sure that you business rules are applied correctly in your algorithme **(throwing the exception if the sensitivity level is bad for example)**

The stub or the fake will allow you to control the sensitivity level return, It's also means that you will have to wrap the **"MIP Library"** inside a class or using IOC

**2. Use integration testing**

When you will have a first working scenario with you unit test, you will be able to make the same with Integration Testing. You will add to your project the material to have a **"production environnement"** adding files with differents sentivities to your test project

**Conclusion**

Of course, I know that my answer is not a working solution but your needs is not simple and cannot be set in a stackoverflow post.
You will need to investigate about double testing & integration testing before making any development if you want to have reliable unit tests.